# $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)\space\space a.e.\text{for all x in E}$$

My Question:

1. How do you interpret this? As you get to the tail of the function sequence, each tail sequence and the function disagree only on negligible sets?
2. Is there a name for this type of convergence other than what we call almost everywhere convergence?
3. Is there any relationship between the a.e. convergence and pointwise convergence or uniform convergence?

These are discussed in the context of constructing the Lebesgue integration theory.

Reference:
$\textit{Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces}$. Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition says that the set $\{x\in E: f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)\}$ has measure zero. Obviously this is something a bit weaker than pointwise convergence. (pointwise convergence is when the set I defined is empty).

As for names: in probability theory this type of convergence is also called "almost sure convergence". The intuition there is that if you pick a point then with probability $1$ it is a point where the sequence converges to the limit random variable.

Comment: Isn't the standard definition that there is a set $X$ such that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise to $f$ for all $x \in X$ and the measure of the complement of $X$ is $0$? This would only be equivalent to your statement in the case of a complete measure space (subsets of measure zero sets are again measurable).

Comment: Your definition is strictly stronger than mine. In your's the set on which $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge needs to be measurable and have measure zero, in mine it only needs to be contained in a measurable set which has measure zero.

Comment: Oh, I get your point. But the set of points where we don't have convergence is measurable anyway, right? The set of points where we have convergence is $\cap_{0<\epsilon\in\mathbb{Q}}\cup_{n_0=1}^\infty\cap_{n=n_0}^\infty \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\}$. This is a measurable set, hence the complement is measurable as well.

Comment: Sure, but only if you assume the $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be measurable.

Comment: Well, yes, I assumed they are all measurable. Most of the time this type of convergence is defined for sequences of measurable functions. (especially when OP has the tag "measure theory" under the question). But yes, I should have written that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

1. It means that $\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)$ for a measurable set $E\subset X$ such that $\mu(X\setminus E)=0$. That is: it doesn't converge just in a set of zero measure (also called a *null* set).
2. I see it just as a.e. pointwise convergence.
3. The *almost everywhere* concept is applied to many different things, not just convergence. Depending of the context it have different meanings. In this context it is a subtype of pointwise convergence.